# Groupby count and ratio based on specific condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
Bookin_ID   Session     Walkin
   1             S1          no
   2             S1          no
   3             S1          no
   4             S1          yes
   5             S1          no
   6             S1          yes
   10            S2          no
   11            S2          yes
   12            S2          no
   13            S2          yes
   14            S2          no
   15            S2          yes
   16            S2          no
   17            S2          no
   18            S2          yes
   19            S2          no
   26            S3          no
   27            S3          no
   28            S3          yes
   29            S3          no
```

From the above I would like to calculate walkin probability for each session as shown below:

```
walkin_prob =  count of walkin = 'yes' in that session / total number of booking in that session
```

For example, for Session = S1, count of Walkin = no is 2 and total number of booking is 6 so the walkin_prob = 2/6 = 0.33.

Similarly for S2, count of Walkin = yes is 4 and total number of booking is 10 so walkin_prob = 4/10 = 0.4. and so on.

Expected output:

```
Bookin_ID     Session      Walkin     walkin_prob
   1             S1          no       0.33
   2             S1          no       0.33
   3             S1          no       0.33
   4             S1          yes      0.33
   5             S1          no       0.33
   6             S1          yes      0.33
   10            S2          no       0.33
   11            S2          yes      0.4
   12            S2          no       0.4
   13            S2          yes      0.4
   14            S2          no       0.4
   15            S2          yes      0.4
   16            S2          no       0.4
   17            S2          no       0.4
   18            S2          yes      0.4
   19            S2          no       0.4
   26            S3          no       0.25
   27            S3          no       0.25
   28            S3          yes      0.25
   29            S3          no       0.25
```

I tried below and that does not work.

```
df['walkin_prob'] = df.groupby('Session')[['Walkin'] == 'yes'].sum()/df.groupby('Session')['Walkin'].sum()
```

And it shows below error

> Column not found: False

Comment: And what did you try? What went wrong? How can we help?

Comment: @jorijnsmit added what I have tried

Comment: Did you get an error? What does it say? What does it tell you about your code? How can we help you interpret that message?

Comment: @jorijnsmit added the errors as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to do this:

```
df['walkin_prob'] = df.groupby('Session')['Walkin'].transform(lambda x: x[x == 'yes'].count() / x.count())
```

When a single value is returned from the function in `transform`, it will use it for each of the rows in the group. The above will give exactly the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. It's just that `[['Walkin'] == 'yes']` is not correct notation. It evaluates to `False` (which is not a column).

You can use `.loc` to filter on `df['Walkin'] == 'yes'`:

```py
df.loc[df['Walkin'] == 'yes'].groupby('Session').sum() / df.groupby('Session').sum()
```

```
         walkin_prob
Session             
S1          0.333333
S2          0.407125
S3          0.250000
```

Comment: I would also suggest changing the `sum` to `count`